# Extract data based on a pattern on a given line number

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to find a line (line number 6) which is like

```
"password": "......."
```

in a file in where all lines start with `"whatever here": "...."`

Then, I want to extract whatever written after the `:` sign and remove all the extra words and characters: "password":"" and take ....... part between the quotation marks.

I want to define it as a new variable (here I name it as user1) because later, I want to replace that variable into a new command in the same script for getting a web address.

I have used this command, but it does not work:

```
 user1=`head -6| grep -v "\<"password:"\>" myfile.txt`

 wget '....$user1&......
```

Can anyone help me please? I have been working on it for several days, but I cannot resolve this problem.

Comment: To set a variable (in bash) to the output of a command you can use this syntax: `a=$(echo abc)` Variable a is now set to abc, `user=$(head -1 afile)` will set user to first line in `afile`.

Comment: Please edit your title to explain your actual problem.

Comment: Example input and example output would help enormously here.

Comment: The "hard" single quotes in your wget example will prevent variable expansion of $user1

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
user1=$(
  sed -n '
    6!d; # disregard any line but the 6th one
    s/^[[:blank:]]*"password"[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p
    q' myfile.txt
)
```

If you want that `$user1` to be passed as a CGI GET parameter, you'll need to do `%XX` encoding in it.

With `ksh93`, you can do:

```
wget "http://host.example/cgi-bin/script?user1=$(printf '%#H' "$user1")"
```

With other shells, you could resort to `perl` to do the URI escaping:

```
uri_escape() {
  perl -MURI::Escape -le 'print map {uri_escape $_} @ARGV' -- "$@"
}

wget "http://host.example/cgi-bin/script?user1=$(uri_escape "$user1")"
```

Or use `curl` instead of `wget` which can encode the parameters by itself:

```
curl -G -O --data-urlencode "user1=$user1" 'http://host.example/cgi-bin/script'
```

Comment: Thank you. But, when I try to replace the variable in the new command to connect to a website as $user1, it gives me error message and the resulting file is empty.

Comment: @JIGIL, see edit. You need to use double quotes if you want variables or command substitutions to be expanded inside.

Answer (score 0):

Assume a data file ('afile') whose contents are:

```
$ cat afile
now
is
the
time
for
"password": "all good men"
to
come
to
the
aid
of
their
country
```

Then the following line of Bash locates the line with `"password":` then extracts the content between the quotation marks:

```
$ user1=$(cat afile | grep '^[[:blank:]]*"password"[[:blank:]]*:' | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*"password":[[:blank:]]*//' | sed 's/"//g')

$ echo $user1
all good men
```

If you know for sure that the line in question is positioned exactly on line-6 then the following also works:

```
$ user1=$(cat afile | sed '6!d' | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*"password":[[:blank:]]*//' | sed 's/"//g')

$ echo $user1
all good men
```